# Counting the number of flows in a tcpdump file

Tags: python, shell, tcpdump

I have a large tcpdump file which I need to parse to identify the number of flows in the capture based on the ( source ip + source port , destination ip + destination port ) pairs. Does tcpdump / any other tool provide any means to obtain such data directly? / Any tips on how to optimize my parser to perform this operation? Any help / leads are very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
tcpdump -r capturefile.dmp | awk '{ print $3 " " $5 "\n" }' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Assuming your tcpdump generates the same output as mine, the awk command will print the source IP+port and the destination IP+port (followed by a colon, which is irrelevant in this case), like so:

```
zangetsu.smcc.loc.56256 scfire-a28.websys.aol.com.http:
```

Since an established connection will use the same portnumbers again you collapse these repeated lines with `sort | uniq`; `wc -l` counts the lines. You will have to divide this number by 2 since IP is bidirectional and it reverses source/destination when sending packets back.

You may want to filter out unwanted packets for UDP and ICMP and whatnot with tcpdump filters, and other stuff with a `grep` before sort.

Comment: Good answer, but the "\n" adds one extra flow. Also the flow is bidirectional  so might need to handle tuple order.